# Using Inkscape command line

Tags: shell, inkscape

For my application i want to use the `File > Revert` functionality of Inkscape, which is not present as a command for using in terminal. How could i get access to the `Revert` functionality for using it as a shell command?

Answer (score 2):

The 'verb' you are looking for is 'FileRevert'. It's there.